# Turn off 'gather_facts' from 'ansible.cfg' or inventory file

Tags: rhel, ansible

Is there a way to turn off `gather_facts` other than at a play level? If I wanted to disable it permanently, is there a way to do it in the `ansible.cfg` or inventory file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `ansible.cfg`:

```
# plays will gather facts by default, which contain information about
# the remote system.
#
# smart - gather by default, but don't regather if already gathered
# implicit - gather by default, turn off with gather_facts: False
# explicit - do not gather by default, must say gather_facts: True
gathering = explicit
```

Answer (score 1):

> *Is there a way to turn off `gather_facts` other than at a play level? If I want to disable it permanently, is there a way to do it in the `ansible.cfg` ...*

Yes, of course. According Ansible documentation [Ansible Configuration Settings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-gathering) about the [The configuration file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#the-configuration-file) and [`DEFAULT_GATHERING`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-gathering) set `gathering = explicit`.

> *Default `implicit`*
>
> *Choices*
>
> - *`implicit` the cache plugin will be ignored and facts will be gathered per play unless `gather_facts: False` is set.*
> - *`explicit` facts will not be gathered unless directly requested in the play.*